# DLL functions and input descriptions?

Tags: vba, dll

I am currently using vba and have found a couple of handy pieces of code on the internet.

However some of these pieces of code use functions from DLL's e.g(user32).

The code works fine but it frustrates me that I have no means of discovering such functionality myself except for stumbling upon code on the internet.

I basically want to know if there is a way of obtaining descriptions of what exactly a specific DLL function does and what the input parameters represent or can this only be done by looking at the DLL's in their original language?

Comment: You may wish to look at http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php  and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190000.

Answer (score 0):

Not in VBA as fas as I know, but [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net) site can help a lot.
Chek how well explained is [LogonUser](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html) for example. Easy to adapt VB.NET to VBA with all that info I think.

Comment: Adapting VB.NET to VBA is not at all trivial. I'm not sure it's any easier than adapting the native C code to one or the other. The worst part is that lots of things *look* the same between VBA and VB.NET, but **aren't** (like the `Integer` type).

Comment: I know it, but the info in pinvoke.net can be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are part of the native Win32 API.

They're all quite well documented on [MSDN, Microsoft's SDK documentation for Windows programmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff657751.aspx).

For example, you might see the `GetParent` function called, which returns a handle to the specified window's parent or owner. The documentation for that function is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510.aspx).

Note how the documentation tells you what the function does, how it is prototyped in a C-style language, what each of its parameters are and what they mean, and what its return value is and what it means. Very comprehensive; guaranteed to answer almost all of your questions. You should definitely read the "Remarks" section for any function which you are unfamiliar. There are a lot of important caveats to the Win32 API—it's a very powerful, but very old C API. There are a lot of arbitrary limitations that the programmers were forced to work around, and now because of backwards compatibility, we've been saddled with those workarounds for generations. The very bottom also tells you what DLL file you need to specify in order to call that function. For example, `GetParent` is found in `user32.dll`.

In just about *every* case that I've tried (and I've gone searching for lots of docs), you can type the name of the function into Google and the appropriate MSDN page will be the first result.